# zeros of a holomorphic function in several variable 

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $n$ complex variables on a domain $D\subset \mathbb C^n$. Let $S$ be  a subset of $D$ such that for a polynomial $P$ in $n$ variable, $P(S)=(a,b)$ for an interval $(a,b)$. Can $f$ be zero on $S$?

What happens if $P(S)=(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q$?

Comment: What does this subset look like? Can it be a Cantor-like set? Non-measurable? Semi-locally simply-connected?

Comment: $D$ can be taken to be an infinite convex domain like a tube in $\mathbb C^n$. 
 
Take for instance $P(z)=z_1^2+\dots +z_n^2+A$ with $A\in \mathbb R$. 
Then $P$ will map $D$ in a parabolic region say $PARB$ on $\mathbb C$. Now $S$ is the pre-image of the set of points on $\mathbb R\cap PARB$.
Can $S$ be as  bad as a cantor set in this case?

Comment: You need to specify what you allow for $S$. By just saying 'subset' you open yourself up to all sorts of pathologies.

Comment: Let us take $S$ to be a measurable set which is path-connected and simply connected. I suppose such a set of points can be constructed so that its image under the polynomial $P$ is $(a,b)$. 

Comment: I don't understand the question, maybe. $0$ is a holomorphic function, and it's going to be zero on any set $S$. 

So let's assume you mean "can $S$ be $f^{-1}(0)$?. Well, a polynomial (or a holomorphic function generally) cannot be real and nonconstant on this $n-1$ dimensional complex analytic variety, if $n>1$.



Comment: Could you edit your question to elaborate on how this problem arose for you?  That might yield clues for making the problem both nontrivial and tractable.  For example, do you have a reason to require $f$ to be nonconstant, or $S$ to have a convex hull with nonempty interior?

Comment: I will redo it as suggested.  $f$ is a holomorphic function on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb C^n$. $(a, b)$ is an open interval which does not contain $0$, and $P$ is a polynomial in $n$ variables.  For every $r\in (a, b)$ define $P_r(z)=P(z)-r$. Then the zero set of $P_r$ is  $\mathbb C$-manifold of dimension $n-1$. If $f$ is zero on the zero sets of $P_r$ for every $r\in (a, b)$ then is $f\equiv 0$?   

The assumption "for every $r\in (a, b)$" can perhaps be changed by something like  "for every $s\in \C$ such that $\Re s$ is constant and $\Im s\in (a, b)\mathbb Q$".



Comment:  a few typos in the last two lines. Read for every $s\in \mathbb C$ .....$\Im s\in (a, b)\cap \mathbb Q$, where $Q$ is rationals. 

Comment: Prof Tom Goodwillie you wrote "a polynomial (or a holomorphic function generally) cannot be real and nonconstant on this n−1 dimensional complex analytic variety, if n>1." Is it a standard fact, could you give a reference or is it easy to prove?